# Page number won't appear on the first page Chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, page-numbering, chapters

I' using the following code to create the table of contents, list of figures, and so on:

```
\documentclass[12pt,envcountsame,envcountchap]{svmono}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % high quality pdf
\usepackage{ucs} % unicode for mac os x
\usepackage{geometry} % Flexible and complete interface to document dimensions.
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{epstopdf} % eps to pdf
\usepackage{rotating} % rotate stuff
\usepackage{lmodern} %Type1-font for non-english texts and characters
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom, etc.
\usepackage{url}
\linespread{1.2}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Use of Times New Roman font
\usefont{T1}{ptm}{m}{n}
\selectfont

\loadglsentries{001-acronyms}   % Load list of acronyms
\loadglsentries{001-symbols}        % Load list of frequent symbols
\makeglossaries
\glsaddall

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}  

\include{100-cover}
\pagestyle{plain} 
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures  
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures} 
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\lstlistoflistings
\end{document}
```

The `\tableofcontents` generates two pages, but the page number only appears on the second page. Since other commands (`\listoffigures`, `\listoftables`, `\lstlistoflistings`) only generate one page, the page number doesn't appear at all. 
I would like to have page number present on all this pages. 
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This is not the normal behavior. We need to see more of the preamble; in particular the class you're using. Are you using `fancyhdr`? As an aside, using `\include` for the cover page doesn't seem best; use `\input`.

Comment: Hello, I'm not using fancyhdr, I've tried to follow some suggestions with this class but still had the same problem. I will follow your advice and change it to input, thank you!

Comment: I get the page number bottom right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very common "problem" that typically follows document classes - not specific to [`svmono`](http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0) - that provide `\chapter`s. The reason for this stems from the fact that the layout of the header on these chapter-first-pages typically look weird, and therefore is set in a different style via something like `\thispagestyle{<chapter-page-style>}` (typically `<chapter-page-style>` is `plain`).

While it is possible to issue

```
\chapter{<title>}
\thispagestyle{<style>}
```

in order to update the forced `<chapter-page-style>` style to `<style>` works for regular chapters, it's not that easy for List-of "chapters" like `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and the like. The reason for this is because the List-of chapter is set as a whole, thereby making it difficult to insert `\thispagestyle{<style>}` at the appropriate (timed) location.

You can resolve this problem through a patch of the List-of commands (using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\@starttoc}{\thispagestyle{plain}\@starttoc}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{\@starttoc}{\thispagestyle{plain}\@starttoc}{}{}
\patchcmd{\listoftables}{\@starttoc}{\thispagestyle{plain}\@starttoc}{}{}
\makeatother
```

or by letting the `empty` page style be equivalent to the `plain` page style:

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@empty\ps@plain
\makeatother
```

Either of the above, inserted in the preamble somewhere should work.

Comment: The page number *is* there.

Comment: Using the second example, the pages show but not in all document. It seems like your first example (patch) works better in my case, but is there any way to hide/remove page number from the cover page? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The `svmono` class is not free and should be used only for submissions to Springer. So either you are preparing a submission and should not tamper with the settings of the class, or you're misusing it.

There is nothing in the `svmono.zip` file that can only be downloaded from Springer that grants permissions to use the files for other purposes. So one *must* assume no permission.

In any case, the class defines

```
\newcommand\chapter{\startnewpage
                    \@ifundefined{thispagecropped}{}{\thispagecropped}
                    \thispagestyle{bchap}%
                    \if@chapnum\else
                       \begingroup
                         \let\@elt\@stpelt
                         \csname cl@chapter\endcsname
                       \endgroup
                    \fi
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
```

and

```
\def\tableofcontents{\@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
 \fi\chapter*{\contentsname \@mkboth{{\contentsname}}{{\contentsname}}}
 \@starttoc{toc}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi}
```

(similarly for `\listoffigure` and `\listoftables`). Since we find

```
\def\ps@bchap{%\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
     \let\@oddhead\@empty\let\@evenhead\@empty
     \def\@oddfoot{\reset@font\small\hfil\thepage}%
     \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot}
```

the page number in *all* chapter starting pages appears at the bottom right of the page, which is what I obtain running your example.

[image]